# Get Instance of ViewController from within extension

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods, viewcontroller

I'd like to get **access** to a **ViewController** from an **extension** and then override a function from a library which should change variables or invoke methods from a specific ViewController (in this case "ViewController").

How can I do that? Or is there a more recommended option?

(Hint: I don't want to instantiate a new VC)

```
import PopupDialog

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //e.g. variable and method to access from extension

    var score: Int = 0;

    func startGame(){
        ...
    }
}
extension PopupDialog{
    open override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //change variables
        //maybe also invoke methods
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `PopupDialog` is using in this code? Is it linked to `ViewController` somehow?

Comment: i don't think you can override methods in extension. Try subclassing instead

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi the PopupDialog is imported in ViewController and its used there

Comment: @LalKrishna it works. I tested it with print("xy") in the console. So I don't want to change something from PopupDialog, I just want to change statements from my ViewController when the function viewWillDisappear() from PopupDialog gets invoked

Comment: what variable you need to change? Do you want to change `ViewController.score` from `PopupDialog`'s `viewWillDisappear` method?

Comment: @LalKrishna Yes, for example. I also need to invoke some methods from there maybe.

Comment: why don't you use Notification or protocols for that?

Comment: @LalKrishna never used it before, so if this is a better option, I'll try it. But is there no possibility to get this done with my thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Notification** or **Protocol** to communicate between ViewControllers

#### Notification Example:

Create an Extension to use Notification names:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let ScoreUpdateNotification = Notification.Name("ScoreUpdateNotification")
}
```

Add Observer method in First ViewController's DidLoad

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(triggerThisMethod), name: Notification.Name.ScoreUpdateNotification, object: nil)

@objc func triggerThisMethod(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        // When the notification arrives, this method will be called
        if let object = notification.object {
            // If there is Object passed with notification you will get it here.
        }
    }
```

To Post Notification

```
let objectToPass = 23
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .ScoreUpdateNotification, object: objectToPass)
```

---

#### Protocol

Create Protocol and a weak variable in ViewController B

```
protocol ProtocolB: class {
    func didUpdateScore(_ score: Int)
}

weak var delegate: ProtocolB?
```

When you Present/Push ViewController B from A

```
let viewControllerB = // ...
viewControllerB.delegate = self
//present viewControllerB
```

Add Protocol Methods to ViewController A

```
extension ViewController: ProtocolA {
    func didUpdateScore(_ score: Int) {
        // Do things
    }
}
```

To trigger methods call:

```
delegate?.didUpdateScore(25)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try both ways, I think I could get in trouble because I only have one ViewController class file and from there I just invoke a new one modally. So I have no file for ViewController B (I'll accept your answer later, when everything is fine)

Comment: `PopupDialog` ? What's this about? Is it a viewcontroller? NB: You don't have to use both way. Use the convenient one. Normally notifications are used when you Trigger multiple observers.

Comment: Yes it is! Worked fine with the notification pattern, but I'm posting the notification in my viewWillDisappear() from the PopUpDialog extension.