# Container View and some problems with it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, uicontainerview

Im just starting with Swift and i can get past this problem i dont know how to run the function inside the ViewController2 from ViewController.

```
import UIKit

class Main: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func onButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "newSegue", sender: self)
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let SecondViewController = ViewController2()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SecondViewController.changeText()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label6: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func changeText() {
        label1.text = "hi"
        label2.text = "how"
        label3.text = "are"
        label4.text = "you"
        label5.text = "doing"
        label6.text = "!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Not allowed to call any function like this. You need to use a delegate or notification observer.

Comment: Have a look at Notifications or Protocols: 
(The answer of this post should help you)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650475/get-instance-of-viewcontroller-from-within-extension/51651287?noredirect=1#comment90268339_51651287

Comment: How is the ViewController2 presented?  Is it in a container view inside `ViewController`?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get a reference to the view controller that is embedded in a container view is to do so in `(prepare(for segue:sender:)`.

When you set up a container view in the storyboard, you will see a segue that links the containing view controller to the contained view controller.  This is an *embed* segue that will fire just after the containing view controller is loaded (but after `viewDidLoad` has completed).  You can use this segue to get a reference to the destination (which will be your instance of `ViewController2`) and store it in a property.  You don't need to make any changes to your `ViewController2` class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var secondViewController: ViewController2?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.secondViewController?.changeText()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
            self.secondViewController = destVC
        }
    }
}
```